# How to loop over generator and output to csv?

Tags: python, csv, generator

Very very very new to python here, so I have a basic question:  I have a function that outputs generators.  I need to loop over them and output to a csv.

```
for i in library.function(bounding box):
      print (library.function2(i))
```

This returns several thousand unique generators.  How do I output the looped info to a csv?  I feel like I keep over complicating this, but I'm still learning.

Thank you!

Comment: Look at the `csv` module.

Comment: Hi there. Pls provide the input you get and the output that you expect. What exactly returns `data.function(...)`?

Comment: Sure: I'm inputting a bounding box and it's returning unique IDs within a generator.  I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open a file handle, then write to the handle:

```
with open('foo.csv', 'w') as f:
    for i in data.function(x,y,z):
        f.write(i)
```

You may need to serialize `i` to a string if `i` is an Object that does not implement `__str()__` or `__unicode__` methods.

Comment: `with open('foo.csv', 'w') as f:`

Comment: This returns:
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Tile

Comment: so you'll have to convert whatever `data.function` returns into a string. I don't know what `Tile` data type is. What does `data.function` even do? You could always try to convert `i` to a string with `str(i)` as long as `Tile` has a `__str__()` method. Another alternative is `repr(i)` if `Tile` implements a `__repr()__` method.